# Is there any way to use Wrap (from Oracle client utilities) as a portable, or easier to be installed on Linux?

Tags: linux, database, oracle, obfuscation, utilities

I was looking for automation in some processes, and one goal would be using *wrap* command (from Oracle client) in the build server, to obfuscate some scripts.
I could install Oracle database utilities on Windows, but I'm having no luck with Ubuntu (WSL), which is the server's OS and where I'd like to use the automation script calling *wrap* command.

Did you have any lucky using this tool on Linux servers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The wrap utility should also exist on the Oracle Database server... it's in $ORACLE_HOME/bin

Comment: @kfinity I guess it would be harder installing the server than the client? At least for Ubuntu / other .deb based distros

Comment: Oh, the build server doesn't have Oracle Database installed? You can probably copy the wrap utility from an existing Oracle database Linux server, if you have one. Otherwise, you might have to download and install the full database software just to get the tiny `wrap` executable.

Comment: I'm trying to install it on a virtual machine - there are some Linux machines with Oracle Database installed here, but I don't have access to them... Either the full client or database installations are giving me headaches